# Calculating days without selling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate how many consecutive days without selling a product are.

Supposing that each row of my dataframe represents one day, already sorted by date.

On this examples, the result should be 1 (day):

```
   sku   center units
0   103896  1   2.0
1   103896  1   0.0
2   103896  1   5.0
3   103896  1   0.0
4   103896  1   7.0
5   103896  1   0
```

this one should be 0 days:

```
   sku   center units
0   103896  2   2.0
1   103896  2   0.0
2   103896  2   5.0
3   103896  2   0.0
4   103896  2   7.0
```

And this one should be 5 days

```
   sku center units
0   103  3   0.0
1   103  3   0.0
2   103  3   0.0
3   103  3   0.0
4   103  3   0.0
```

The only way that I found was doing something like this:

```
def unsold_period(x):
    if x['units'].tail(1).values[0] == 0 :
        last = x.index.tail(1).values[0]
        first = x[x['units'] > 0].index.tail(1).values[0]
        return int((first - last))
    else:
        return  0
```

Then:

```
df.groupby([sku, center]).apply(unsold_period)
```

Is there some approach to do this just using pandas vectorization on groups (df.groupby([sku, center]))?

Comment: does your original dataframe have a date col?

Comment: Yes, I have this column as well.

Comment: if you add the date we can create a conditional column with the `cumsum` which can add a counter for any 0's by SKU and I assume center? but we need to see an example of your original dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use cumsum and count number of zeros at last

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 103896, 1, 2.0], [1, 103896, 1, 0.0], [2, 103896, 1, 5.0], [3, 103896, 1, 0.0], [4, 103896, 1, 0.0], [5, 103896, 1, 0.0]], columns=('id', 'sku', 'center', 'units'))
result = np.sum((df.units > 0).iloc[::-1].cumsum() == 0)
print(result)
```